How to detect and properly handle signal.SIGTERM in Windows 11
In my Python program, I need to detect and gracefully handle signal.SIGTERM
I use the following two small Python programs to send and handle signal.SIGTERM:
Receiver and handler:
import signal, time, os

def handle_signal(signum, frame):
    global running
    print ("Received signal", signum)
    running = False

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_signal)

# Write the PID to a file
with open("pid.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(os.getpid()))

running = True
while running:
    time.sleep(1)


Sender:
import os, signal, time

# Read PID from file
with open("pid.txt", "r") as f:
    pid = int(f.read())

time.sleep(5)  # Optional delay

# Send SIGUSR1 signal
os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)



As soon as I send signal.SIGTERM to the receiver, it gets terminated, but handle_signal is never called.
Why? How can I make this setup work under Windows 11 or Windows platform?

You can't use SIGTERM like this on Windows. See this discussion

Perhaps I should use a dev container instead.
